# Rewrite and keep pattern matching?

Tags: lambda, pattern-matching, agda

I have the following definition:

```
ren-refl′ : ∀ {Γ i t} (ts′ : List Ty) → (e : Tm {i} (Γ <>< ts′) t) → ren (keep* ts′ reflᵣ) e ≡ e
ren-refl′ {Γ} ts′ (var v)  rewrite keep*-refl {Γ} ts′ | ren-var-refl v = refl
ren-refl′ {Γ} ts′ (con e)  rewrite keep*-refl {Γ} ts′ | ren-con-refl e = refl
```

I would like to factor out the rewriting by `keep*-refl {Γ} ts′` since we can do that (and do that uniformly) before pattern matching on the `e` argument.

The closest I got is with a pattern matching lambda:

```
ren-refl′ {Γ} ts′ rewrite keep*-refl {Γ} ts′ = λ
  { (var v) → cong var (ren-var-refl v)
  ; (con e) → cong con (ren-con-refl e)
  }
```

However, I don't like it because it requires me to do some `cong` shuffling that I wouldn't need with a straight `rewrite`; and I can't do a `rewrite` in a lambda.

Comment: I presume that it wouldn't do to factor-out by creating a separate function that gets called after the first `rewrite`? The factored-out function would then perform the `ren-*-refl` rewrites. This adds some tedium that I suspect you don't want.

Comment: Yeah factoring out the second step into a separate function is exactly what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

You might try [`Tactic.Reflection.Reright`](https://github.com/UlfNorell/agda-prelude/blob/master/src/Tactic/Reflection/Reright.agda) (sic) which I created in the `agda-prelude`. I imagine that you could replace the `cong *`s with `reright`. Caveat: I have not maintained that for some months and no longer use it.

Answer (score 1):

Quite often `case_of_` and `case_return_of_` from `Function` work fine inside lambdas, e. g:

```
open import Function

... λ {(var v) → case ren-var-refl v of λ {refl → refl}}
```

Comment: I like the idea behind it (and would hope to be able to abstract it further away with a `syntax` declaration), but it doesn't work for my particular use case: `I'm not sure if there should be a case for the constructor refl,
because I get stuck when trying to solve the following unification
problems (inferred index ≟ expected index):
  ren-con reflᵣ e ≟ e`